# Uxpin scrollbars

Tags: user-interface, web

i want to know if there is any possible way to remove uxpin exported html scrollbars. I thought scrollbars are only available in preview of our design but, it is in exported html too.

I didn't try anything because I didn't get any results from research.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.